# Convert one time to Another in Actuate BIRT

Tags: java, timezone, birt

Task is to convert date time from one time zone to another in BIRT.

Specifically, it’s related to dynamic dates. For instance where report runs and there is a report parameter like “Order Date” = “Today”.
All our server run in GMT time zone. So, when report runs on “3/16/2016 2:00AM GMT”, in “America/New_York” it’s still “3/15/2016”.

When users login into Actuate UI, the provide user’s time zone

These time zones are “understood” by java. I could easy take the current time in GMT and convert it, let’s say, to “America/New_York” and determine what date is “Today” in this time zone:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(“GMT”));
c.setTime(new Date());
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

So, I need the reliable way of converting GMT date time into user’s time zone.

Comment: Want to see user time zone as Time stamp rather than Server Time zone time stamp but the area where the data will be viewed is dynamic, so the time zone should act as dynamic